# Ember js 2, Using scss @import in my app.scss production doesn’t remove comments in final css

Tags: javascript, ember.js, sass, ember-data, ember-cli

In my app.scss file I'm using

`@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";`

because I'm using (and sometimes changing) some Bootstrap variable into my app.scss.

I found that with `ember build -prod` it doesn't remove comments from within Bootstrap imports in my final app.css.

So in my production css I have this:

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v4.0.0-beta (https://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2017 The Bootstrap Authors
 * Copyright 2011-2017 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */address,dl,ol,p,ul{margin-bottom:1rem}body,caption{text-align:left}........
```

Why?

How can I remove those superfluous comments?

Comment: Can you confirm that ```-prod``` is just a typo here in your post? As it probably should be ```--prod```.

Comment: No, it is `ember build -prod`. My question is not about this.

Comment: Thanks for explanation

Answer (score 0):

`/*!` is a "special" comment due to the `!` character at the end which will not be stripped from the build. It usually contains mandatory license information, which means that it would actually be illegal to strip it if you use any Bootstrap assets.